# Windows Apps like Store, Weather, etc, crashing

Tags: windows-10, crash, cmd.exe, cache, windows-store

So For some reason everytime I try to open a windows app like Weather, Store, etc, they do wierd things. for example 'Weather' crashes while launching, 'Store' crashes when clicking on an app. Anyone have any ideas?

I have tried:

running this command in PowerShell:

powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register $Env:SystemRoot\WinStore\AppxManifest.xml

but got a bunch of red errors :/

I also tried 'wsreset.exe' didnt work.

and I also tried deleting the store cache folders

Here is a video of the problem I am having (sorry for the terrible quality): https://youtu.be/Yn3abTznxLA

Comment: You have system corruption.  Upgrade to version 1607, using the upgrade assistant, similar tool to the media creation tool.  It is your best hope to fix your problem

Comment: I second Ramhound's suggestion. I had similar problems with Version 1511, I upgraded to 1607 using an ISO and all works fine now.

Comment: Ok, I am currently running 1511, ill update and see if it fixes the problems. Thanks!

Comment: Yessssss, Thank you Ramhound and Peter Hahndrof, updating to 1607 solved my problem!

Comment: Feel free to submit an answer to your question.  You don't have to give me any credit since you figured it out on your own.